# How to Invoke Multiple webmethod URLs with different filename at once in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, spring-mvc, download

I am very new to Spring Boot project.

I am writing backend code where I have a webmethod url which can download only one file at a time based on fileNo. It is invoked from the front-end when user enters fileNo and submits.

User can enter maximum 5 fileNo(comma-separated) at one time.

In that case I have to take each file no and and set it into my url, invoke it which will download 5 files and put it in one common folder.

**Below code is working for one FileNo and downloading the file,**

**Is there anyway where I can set and invoke all 5 URLs concurrently, download all 5 files and put it in a same folder.**
Or If I have to set it one by one in my URL then how to do it. What is the best way to do this. (went through few similar posts but couldn't fine anything for my solution). Looking for a solution here. Thanks

```
@SneakyThrows
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Server Error")
})
public ResponseEntity getCollateralDownloadData(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
    String wmURL = "https://www.qa.referencesite.com/invoke/File_appDesigns.process:processTpfQuery?prdType=PTO&tpf_aif=one&SALESNO=&PRODNO=&OASN="+fileName;
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.build()
                .exchange(wmURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .body(response.getBody());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Collateral Download Created successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches depending on your need :

- The client may trigger requests concurrently, so the client has to send a request for each fileNo and you backend deals with it
- The client may trigger only one request, so your backend should be modified to trigger subsequent calls, wait for result and build a common response. You may use Spring WebFlux facilities or Java ExecutorService.invokeAll() method to manage subsequent parallels requests.

Regards.

Comment: Hi, responding late but now I was able to implement this using ExecutorService

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete Flow of code what I have done.

@RestController
public class DownloadOAFileController {

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate;

private static final int MYTHREADS = 30;

@SneakyThrows
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadzippedFile/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Server Error")
})
public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadzipFiles(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
   
    downloadMultipleFilesToRemoteDiskUsingThread(fileName);



    String zipFilename = "/Users/kumars22/Downloads/Files.zip";
    File file = new File(zipFilename);
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition",
                String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",file.getName()));
        headers.add("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, no-revalidate");
        headers.add("pragma","no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires","0");

        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(resource);
     return responseEntity;
    }
```

//Created a Directory where all files will be downloaded (Got some space in AWS for actual implementation.

```
    public static void createDirectory() {
        File file = new File("/Users/kumars22/Downloads/Files");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
    }

public static void downloadMultipleFilesToRemoteDiskUsingThread( String fileName ) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    createDirectory();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);
    String[] serials = fileName.split(",");
    String[] wmURLs = new String[serials.length];
    for (int i =0;i<serials.length;i++) {
        wmURLs[i] = "https://www.qa.referencesite.com/invoke/File_appDesigns.process:processTpfQuery?prdType=PTO&tpf_aif=one&SALESNO=&PRODNO=&OASN="+serials[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < wmURLs.length; i++) {

        String url = wmURLs[i];
        Runnable worker = new MultipleCallThreadController(url,fileName,"James");
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    // Wait until all threads are finish
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

    }
    zipFiles("/Users/kumars22/Downloads/Files","/Users/kumars22/Downloads/Files.zip");
    System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");

}

//Zip the Folder having all files
public static void zipFiles(String sourceDirPath, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
    Path p = Files.createFile(Paths.get(zipFilePath));
    Path pp = Paths.get(sourceDirPath);
    try (ZipOutputStream zs = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(p));
         Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(pp)) {
        paths
                .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path))
                .forEach(path -> {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(pp.relativize(path).toString());
                    try {
                        zs.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                        Files.copy(path, zs);
                        zs.closeEntry();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println(e);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```